# Redirect to Controller with query params outside of Controller context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, httpcontext, response.redirect

I've looked around online quite a bit, but haven't been able to figure out a solution to my current predicament. As the title suggest I am attempting to redirect a user to one of my view controllers with the following code:

```
// this is in a service that's beyond the Controller scope
httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Login");
```

This works fine; however, I need to pass in a query param as well. Essentially I'm looking to do something like this:

```
// this is in a service that's beyond the Controller scope
httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Login?NoAccess=true");
```

Where my View Controller looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("~/Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery]bool noAccess = false)
{
     // implementation
}
```

As one might imagine, this doesn't work and the value isn't passed to my controller.

**Is it possible to pass query param(s) using a redirect outside of a Controller context?**

Thanks,
Ruben

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with what you have for the client. It seems like a problem with the configuration for your mvc. Maybe the NoAccess is case sensitive. If you use your browser to goto the url and the params does it work?

Comment: So specifying the query params directly in the redirect url httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Login?NoAccess=true") looks good to you? I tested out the query directly in the browser and it was picking up the NoAccess param. Hmmm.

Comment: I'd be curious to debug the redirect header info from the http request and see if it's removing the querying

Comment: Oh sweet that's something I didn't think of. I'll circle back around and check it out. Preciate your time.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Just got back into the office. If you're still curious, it unfortunately looks like the query is being stripped for some reason. I also tried adding a header to the httpcontext.Request and httpcontext.Response object to no avail. This is an older project that I just jumped onto, and I'm beginning to think that there may be some middleware somewhere that's modifying the httpcontext because somehow there is a "returnUrl" query param being added to the httpContext.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override async  Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
   {

       context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
       var url = context.Request.Headers["Referer"];//Url for go back
       var errorMessage = "An error occured."; //Error Message
       var errorCode = 500; 
       var redirectUrl = string.Format("/hata?url={0}&errorMessage={1}&errorCodes={2}", url, errorMessage, errorCode);
       context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
   }
```

You can use **string.Format()** for sending query parameters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `RedirectToAction` or `RedirectToRoute` instead. Will return a IActionResult to do the redirect. With it you can specify an object with the parameters. Like this:

```
public IActionResult Action()
{
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "ControllerName", new {
        noAccess = true
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I need to do this outside of the MVC controller context though. This particular piece of code is executing in a service.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
public IActionResult Action()
{
    return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName") + "?noAccess=true"));
}
```

Also, you can try adding entire url like :

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    // ...entire url
    return Redirect("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Even you could return a JsonResult with the new url and perform the redirect with javascript.

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    // ...
    return Json(new {url = "http://www.example.com"});
}

$.post("@Url.Action("YourAction")", function(data) {
    window.location = data.url;
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I need to do this outside of the MVC controller context though. This particular piece of code is executing in a service.

Comment: This answer is not helpful and it needs to be done outside of the controller context